# webpack babel css @ illegal token

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have converted my ReactJS project from creact-react-app to webpack node SSR (server side rendering), I have solved dozens of errors and dependencies  and other problems. But I cannot solve and google out one issue after starting nodejs server:

```
node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @charset "UTF-8";
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Only thing I can do is to comment the style and not use it which is not good. Already tried different loaders, webpack configurations,... but non of them worked.

Here is my webpack config clean without css loaders, so i hope someone will help to fill and explain the gap. I want to achieve:

- Ignore css files for the server
- Collect all css files, merge them, minify the merged, move to ./build/assets/css/app.css

  ```
  var webpack = require('webpack');
  var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
  var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

  var serverPlugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development') }),
    //new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') }),
  ];

  var clientPlugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false }, sourceMap: false }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/index.css', { allChunks: true })
  ];

  var commonLoaders = [
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
    }
  ];

  var server = {
    entry: './src/server.js',
    output: {
      path: './build',
      filename: 'server.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    target: 'node',
    externals: nodeExternals(),
    plugins: serverPlugins,
    module: {
      loaders: [].concat(commonLoaders)
    }
  };

  var client = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: './build/assets/js',
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: clientPlugins,
    module: {
      loaders: [].concat(commonLoaders)
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
  };

  module.exports = [server, client];
  ```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see you using a css-loader in your webpack

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I mentioned in the question "Here is my webpack config clean without css loaders" I have removed the loaders, because they did not worked. Does not matter what i have tried, code compiled and after running "node server.js" it threw this error.